# Why .save( ) is not and throwing error as ``TypeError: sourceData.save is not a function``?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here is the code of my source model:

```
const sourceSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        url:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        data:{
            posts:[
                {
                    postId: {
                        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        ref: 'Post',
                        required: true
                    }
                }
            ]
            
        },
        oldState:{
            type: Array,
        },
        currentState:{
            type: Array
        }

    }
);
```

I have a source saved in the database and now I want to update the `currentState` value and save it.
articles is an array of objects `[{....},{.....},{.....}]`

Here is my updation code:

```
Source.find({name: 'National News'})
              .then(sourceData=>{
                  console.log(sourceData);
                  sourceData.currentState= articles;
                  return sourceData.save();
              })
              .then(result=>{
                  console.log(result);
                  next();
              })
              .catch(err=>{
                  console.log(err);
              })
```

I am able to see in the console that the correct source has been selected as `console.log(sourceData)` gives the right data but after that, I get the error as `TypeError: sourceData.save is not a function`

I also tried using `sourceData.markModified('currentState')` before `sourceData.save()` but then it started to give `TypeError: sourceData.markModified is not a function`.

I even tried `sourceData.update()` but that also did not work.

I am new to node.js and the tutorial which I followed only used .save() to update data and I was working there. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.find` method returns an array as the result. You might want to use `.findOne` instead.